# Running a batch file from another batch file from shared location

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which has series of commands (abc.bat). I need to copy this file into C:\abc\xyz folder and after copying i need to run the abc.bat file from a shared location.

Comment: `copy abc.bat c:\abc\xyz & c:\abc\xyz\abc.bat `

Comment: could you please show us what you attempted so far and where you are stuck. we can help you overcome a problem, but you have to be specific. tell us what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

The copy command would be the same as if you were typing it directly into a command prompt:

```
copy abc.bat c:\abc\xyz
```

Be sure to include the path for the original file location if it isn't in the same location as the current batch file is running from.

To run a batch file from another batch file, you would use the `call` keyword.

```
call c:\abc\xyz\abc.bat
```